# Email address verification ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise

I have been following Michael Hartl tutorial for creating my first rails app.
I have created a working sign-up and sign-in model for the app.
I need to add a way for the app to send a confirmation token to the email address a user used to register to the app to ensure that the email address used is actually a genuine email address.

Initally I wanted to use devise confirmable module, but i'm having so much trouble trying to integrate just that module into my existing sign-up and sign-in model. 
Is there any guide i can follow that illustrate a way to integrate just that confirmable module into my app?
If there isn't any, are there any modules or functions or gems or plugins or guide out there i can use to verify user's email address (ensure they actually exist, not just valid {i have done the validation using regex} ).

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest you finish the tutorial as is then move on to making your own project, in which you can use devise entirely.

Comment: verifying if the email address is real is difficult that is why most sites send an email to that address to confirm the user owns it prior to confirming the user. Which is not very difficult if you look into mailers. You could possibly do this by using command line tools like nslookup through a smtp or capture bounced emails but implementation could be tricky. You can look at email_veractiy_checker but please note as it states this could cause you to be blacklisted if you are hitting the same domain too often.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use email_verifier gem. ([link](https://github.com/kamilc/email_verifier))

email_verifier gem is using smtp for check email.

To get info about realness of given email address, email_verifier connects with a mail server that email's domain points to and pretends to send an email. Some smtp servers will not allow you to do this if you will not present yourself as a real user.